# Which type of certificate should I use for code-signing a Windows desktop application?

Tags: windows, code-signing, signing

I am looking for a certifier for my Windows app, and I am wondering which certificate type I should choose for the application of my startup. I saw that there are mainly two types - so-called **OV** and **EV** certificates. A quick summary from [SSL.com](https://www.ssl.com/faqs/which-code-signing-certificate-do-i-need-ev-ov/#:%7E:text=EV%20code%20signing%20certificates%20require,web%20server%27s%20SSL%2FTLS%20certificate.) (**for code-signing a desktop application**)

> An EV code signing certificate offers an immediate reputation with Microsoft SmartScreen, so your users will never have to click through a SmartScreen warning in Windows.

> With an OV certificate, SmartScreen reputation must be built organically, as users download and install your files. SmartScreen warnings may occur until enough software proves sufficiently popular with Windows users for SmartScreen to view it as “well known.”

I understand the differences, and most articles refer to them in the use-case of Web SSL certificates. But would you recommend an **EV** certificate for a desktop application from a startup? Or is it not worth the money? Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: We never used EV in a large company, it doesn't give much especially when used in a corporate environment where firewall and SmartScreen are typically disabled. OV is fully enough for most of the use cases. So that depends on the use case.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but you mentioned firewall and Smartscreen and it seems you are referring to SSL certificates for web. In my case it is about code-signing a desktop application

Comment: I was referring to code-signing certs. Regular web certs have no interaction with SmartScreen :)

Comment: It actually does, that's why I asked https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/what-is-smartscreen-and-how-can-it-help-protect-me-1c9a874a-6826-be5e-45b1-67fa445a74c8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real answer here is that you need to be able to cover the cost of the cert, only you know whether you will make enough money from your app for it. The increase in downloads between the two is unlikely to be very big.

Taking SSL.com as an example, OV certificates are offered for 2 years at $232 but EV is $598. If you think that the fairly small percentage increase in downloads will cover this then go for it. It will look more professional that way. After all, $366 to a popular app is peanuts. But if you think your app will not be popular or won't make money, don't waste your cash.